# Why does `std::mbrlen` on mingw-w64 always return one (`1`)

Tags: c++, mingw-w64, multibyte-functions

When I compile the following source code in mingw-w64, I am always getting 1 (one) byte from the [`std::mbrlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrlen):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <clocale>
#include <cstring>
#include <cwchar>

void print_mb(const char* ptr)
{
  std::size_t index{0};
  const char* end = ptr + std::strlen(ptr);
  int len;
  while((len = std::mbrlen(ptr, end-ptr, nullptr)) > 0)
  {
    std::printf("Character #%zu is %i bytes long.\n", index++, len);
    ptr += len;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
  const char* str = "\x7a\xc3\x9f\xe6\xb0\xb4\xf0\x9d\x84\x8b";
  print_mb(str);
}
```

*the sample code is based on code from [`std::mbrtowc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrtowc) page*

After I have compiled this sample under mingw-w64 with

```
gcc sample.cxx
```

I get the following output from the program:

```
Character #0 is 1 bytes long.
Character #1 is 1 bytes long.
Character #2 is 1 bytes long.
Character #3 is 1 bytes long.
Character #4 is 1 bytes long.
Character #5 is 1 bytes long.
Character #6 is 1 bytes long.
Character #7 is 1 bytes long.
Character #8 is 1 bytes long.
Character #9 is 1 bytes long.
```

But if I compile the same code with "online" compiler on the [cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrtowc), for example, **or** with GCC under Arch Linux (again with simple `gcc sample.cxx`), **or** with Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 (`cl sample.cxx`), **or** with Intel C++ compiler 2018 (`icl sample.cxx`), I get this:

```
Character #0 is 1 bytes long.
Character #1 is 2 bytes long.
Character #2 is 3 bytes long.
Character #3 is 4 bytes long.
```

What may cause this behavior of the `std::mbrlen` under mingw-w64? Thanks.

---

My Microsoft Windows host is Microsoft Windows 10 x86-64. Compilation under mingw-w64, Microsoft Visual C++ and Intel C++ made on this host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does not support utf8 via the C and C++ locales.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx

> The set of available locale names, languages, country/region codes, and code pages includes all those supported by the Windows NLS API except code pages that require more than two bytes per character, such as UTF-7 and UTF-8.

Additionally, the locale names on Windows are different than on Linux, e.g. `setlocale( LC_ALL, "English_United States.1252" );`

The C and C++ locale system is implementation defined, and the only usable implementation is the one in Linux (glibc).

On Windows if you want UTF-8 or other Unicode stuff you need to resort to Windows API or to other libraries.

Comment: But why do I get correct results on Microsoft Windows if I compile **the same** code with Microsoft Visual C++ or Intel C++?

Comment: can you double check that, and also check the return value of setlocale.

Here I get as expected 9 chars http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual

Comment: It turns out that you were right: `std::setlocale` fails on mingw-w64 (it returns `nullptr`). **But** `std::setlocale` succeeds (returns "en_US.utf8") in a program compiled with MSFT VC++ 2017, even the documentation says the function will fail. This is because programs built by mingw-w64 and MSFT VC++ 2017 use different C run-time libraries. Thanks for help!